# Spring boot with IntellijIdea : auto complete not working in pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm new with **Spring-boot** and **Maven**. I have problem in adding dependency to my `pom.xml`.

I using Intellij IDEA and for every single dependency I should write the whole `<groupId`> and `<artifactId>` from my knowledge that I think this is not good idea!  intellisense not working in pom file.

for example I want to add `jack-son` and Intellisense just auto creates block of dependency without value! but I need help to fill "artifactId" and when I type "`j`" I expect to load "`jackson-dataformat-xml`"

I do not how to activate intellisense in pom.xml

Comment: If you are new to Maven, my recommendation is that you stop using it, and start using Gradle instead. Maven is very verbose, and needs to be installed on every machine before you can build. Gradle (warpper) is checked into VCS and does not need to be installed (and is self versioned)

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek may you right cause I familiar to Gradle but I'm in course that should use maven. so I should find out how to add dependency to maven in pom with auto complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij provides Live Templates functionality for this very purpose.

In pom.xml, write dep and press tab key, it should create the skeleton xml tag for dependency.

[image: Intellij IDEA Live Templates]

You can also add/edit templates from same settings panel.

---

I misinterpreted the question. To be able to auto-complete ***names of the dependencies/jars***, please update the Maven repository index from Intellij settings.

Intellij suggests names of these dependencies based on local repository and maven repository index.

[image: maven update repo index]

[image: intellij auto-complete of jar names]

Comment: It is work and creates for example dependency block. but it does not help to fill "artifactId" for example I want to add jack-son and when I type "j" i expect to load "jackson-dataformat-xml"

Comment: @kenji updated answer. I had misinterpreted your question. Please check it out and let me know how it goes.